# Simplify Trigonometric Expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I need to simplify this expression

$$\frac{\tan\theta + \cos\theta}{\cos\theta \sin\theta}-\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}$$

I got   $\frac{1}{\cos \theta \sin\theta}$ as an answer but im not sure if this is correct. Can anyone give the steps on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following

$$\eqalign{
  & \,\,\,\,{{\tan \theta  + \cos \theta } \over {\cos \theta \sin \theta }} - {1 \over {{{\cos }^2}\theta }} = {{{{\sin \theta } \over {\cos \theta }} + \cos \theta } \over {\cos \theta \sin \theta }} - {1 \over {{{\cos }^2}\theta }}  \cr 
  &  = {{\sin \theta  + {{\cos }^2}\theta } \over {{{\cos }^2}\theta \sin \theta }} - {1 \over {{{\cos }^2}\theta }}  \cr 
  &  = {{\sin \theta  + {{\cos }^2}\theta  - \sin \theta } \over {{{\cos }^2}\theta \sin \theta }}  \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {\sin \theta }} \cr} $$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\frac{\tan\theta + \cos\theta}{\cos\theta \sin\theta}-\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}=\frac{\cos \theta(\tan\theta+\cos\theta)-\sin \theta}{\cos^2\theta \sin\theta}$$

and $\cos\theta \tan \theta=\sin\theta$. The answer is $\frac{1}{\sin\theta}$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\dfrac{\tan\theta}{\cos\theta\sin\theta}=\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta\sin\theta}=\dfrac1{\cos^2\theta}$$